# What's the recommended procedure when you need to stop using the SD Card?

Tags: sd-card, dual-sim

I have a ASUS Zenfone ZE520KL which has a hybrid card slot.

I've been using one SIM card and one SD card for some months and now I need to use two SIM cards.

I need to stop using the SD card so I can use the slot for another SIM card.

My phone's memory can hold all data in the SD card as of today.

So apart from physical procedure to exchange them what I need to do with some apps data on it?

Camera photos go to there and I know where to change but some apps deliberate use the SD card for some internal purpose and I don't know how to safely start to use all this data without corrupt anything.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't used your card as internal storage using adoptable storage feature or apps like link2sd than you shouldn't worry about anything, you just pull out card. But if your photos, and some other files are on sd card and you need it on phone than you should transfer it to internal storage via some file manager. Only trouble you can get is that some apps requires sd card and they won't work I think that world of tanks is one of them..

Comment: I'm using as separate storage. I'm just afraid I can lose some data because there is an Android/data folder with a lot of apps data.

Comment: @Vitor Canova In that data folder is mostly cache from apps, and content downloaded trought that apps, however that data will still be on sd card if you need it and phone should work just fine without sd card.